# Editing a line in a text file using temp file C

Tags: c, file, text-files, file-copying

I am trying to edit a line in a textfile but i have an unexpected behavior while i am editing the file. What i want to do is adjust a specific line (points     : 100) of a text that looks like. In the function i pass arguments by value the new coins to be adjusted and the offset of the file with ftell->user_point. What i get as an output is weird. I try to copy the rest of the file to a temp,with an edited line, and then copy it back to the original file from the point that i copied to temp.(thats the user_point offset with ftell).
Here is the original fie with entries like that:

```
...    
_______________________________________
    nickname     : geo
    password     : cuvctq
    Name         : george
    Surname      : papas
    points       : 100
    participated : 
    past draws   : 0
    Chosen No.   : 
    future draws : 0
    Registered   : Sun Feb 05 19:23:50 2012
...
```

What i get after 2nd edit run is:

```
...
    _______________________________________
    nickname     : geo
    password     : cuvctq
    Name         : george
    Surname      : papaspoints       : 98
    participated : 
    past draws   : 0
    Chosen No.   : 
    future draws : 0
    Registered   : Sun Feb 05 19:23:50 2012
...
At the end of the text i get one extra \n after i edit the 
file whch is something i dont want :/
```

and so further edit will spoil the text...
I also get an EXTRA \n at the end of the line which, at least what i think so, is due to `"r+"` mode which is something that i also dont want...

```
void coins_adjust(int coins_new,int user_point)
{
    int lines,i,ln_point_copy;
    char buffer[50],buff_copied[50];
    FILE *lottary,*temp;

    memset(buff_copied,'\0',sizeof(char)*50);
    lottary=fopen("customers.txt","r");
    temp=fopen("temp.txt","w");
    fseek(lottary,user_point,SEEK_SET);
    for (lines=0;lines<5;lines++)
    {
        memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(char)*50);
        if (lines==5)
            ln_point_copy=ftell(lottary);       //from TEMP to CUSTOMERS
        fgets (buffer ,50 , lottary);
    }
    coins_new+=atoi(buffer+15);

    strncpy(buff_copied,buffer,15);     //copy 15 chars and fill with null
    memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(char)*50);
    itoa (coins_new,buffer,10);          //fix the new line to be entered
    strcat(buff_copied,buffer);          //the edited line is as it is supposed
    strcat(buff_copied,"\n");            //to be with \n at the end.
    puts(buff_copied);

    printf("%s",buff_copied);fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(temp,"%s",buff_copied);
    for(i=getc(lottary); i!=EOF; i=getc(lottary))  //copy to temp
    {
        putc(i, temp);
    }
    fclose(lottary);
    fclose(temp);

    temp=fopen("temp.txt","r");
    lottary=fopen("customers.txt","r+");
    fseek(lottary,ln_point_copy,SEEK_SET);
    for(i=getc(temp); i!=EOF; i=getc(temp))     //copy until eof
    {
        putc(i, lottary);
    }
    fclose(lottary);fclose(temp);

}
```

I have debugged the program and everything seems to work at least on what values are passed to the arrays where i store the line chars but i cant see why it ignores the `\n` of the previous line when i try to copy it back to the original... There seems to be a `\r` char that i cant get rid of while i copy back to the original...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not read one line at a time, and if it contains the thing you want to change then change it, and write out the line to the new file. Then the actual position of the line you want to change can be anywhere, and you don't have to worry about your program if the format of the file changes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually thats what i am doing more or less but those entries can be hundreds etc. So i need to edit the line and place it where it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was more thinking about something like this:

```
void change_points(int new_points)
{
    FILE *input  = fopen("customers.txt", "r");
    FILE *output = fopen("temp.txt", "w");

    char buffer[256];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input))
    {
        /* Look for the correct line */
        /* Can also use e.g. "if (strncmp(buffer, "points", 6) == 0)"
         * if it's at the start of the line
         */
        if (strstr(buffer, "points") != NULL)
        {
            int old_points;

            sscanf(buffer, "%*s : %d ", &old_points);

            /* Format how you like it */
            fprintf(output, "%-13s: %d\n", "points", new_points + old_points);
        }
        else
            fputs(buffer, output);
    }

    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);

    /* The file "temp.txt" now contains the modifeed text */
    /* Copy either using "fgets"/"fputs", or using "fread"/"fwrite" */

    input  = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("customers.txt", "w");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input))
        fputs(buffer, output);

    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);
}
```

It's shorter, simpler, maybe more effective (looping over line-by-line instead of char-by-char), and the line you are looking for can be anywhere in the file without you knowing its exact position.

Comment: Well i need to know where it is since there are hundrends of registrations in the file not only 1 :( I still dont get it though why it miss the \n after the 2nd try.

Comment: I rewrote my code completely and it works but i still dont get it why it didnt work. Something seemed to be missplaced with the r+ file mode. :(